# Rails ActiveRecord object not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this table that stores serialized objects:

```
class CachedObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :data
  validates_uniqueness_of :key
end
```

The data column stores a serialized object indexed by key.  Pretty simple.  I'm running this code to test:

```
key = "test"
obj = {"test" => "test"}
row = CachedObject.find_or_create_by_key key
row.data = obj.to_json
row.save
```

The object is getting created, but it's not saving back to the database.  No error messages.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What about `save!`? Is there already data in the table?

Comment: your obj and key have the same key values .. try obj = {"test1" => "test"} and it will work fine

Comment: What is the difference between "save" and "save!" ?

Comment: The bang method shows the stack trace in the console.

Comment: @Raghu Can you explain why that would be a problem?

Comment: @DaveNewton, it's still not dumping anything to the screen.  =/

Comment: @DaveNewton he si doing a find and create by key in when trying to find by key and his key is "test" which will create a value in the db with the key as "test" and value as "". then he is assigning the value of the obj to the same row which has the key as "test" . Now that he has created a key with "test" during the find his second attempt to save will fail because of the uniquess validation.

Comment: @Raghu, the dummy object is getting serialized with the to_json call before being set to the data field.  It has no effect on the key.

Comment: @Raghu You're suggesting that you can't save a record after modifying its attributes? He's not creating a new record, he's updating. The value of obj isn't relevant, it's being serialized as a json string.

Comment: @kid_drew try printing row.valid? before your row.save and see if it returns false

Comment: I'd add that Rails already supports serialized columns, btw, there's no need to do it manually.

Comment: row.valid? returns true.  Thanks for the heads up on serialized columns.

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with my test db connection.  I just created a dummy user and saved it, and it also didn't write to the db.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. `.save` returns `true` or `false`. `.save!` raises errors. If you need to know why something is going wrong with a (somewhat) detailed message, use `.save!`.
2. If `key` is not unique, the data will not be saved because the model will not pass validation. Try running `Model.where(:key => 'test').destroy_all` and reevaluate.